# CSS Grid—optional row at the top

Tags: css, css-grid

I am stumbling into CSS grids. Right now I have such a setup:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:  repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
  grid-template-areas:
    "msg    msg    msg    msg"
    "left   left   right  right"
    "left   left   right  right"
    "footer footer footer footer";
}
```

And that is working quite well. I would like to have the first row optional, since there is not always as message to display. Right now, the space is left blank, what is kind of what I expected.

Is the only way to do that, to add class to the container, if a message is there and than change that to:

```
.container {
  /*stuff from above*/

  grid-template-areas:
    "left   left   right  right"
    "left   left   right  right"
    "footer footer footer footer";
}

.container.msg {
  grid-template-areas:
    "msg    msg    msg    msg"
    "left   left   right  right"
    "left   left   right  right"
    "footer footer footer footer";
}
```

or can I tell the grid to hide empty areas?

Comment: row is set at 100px at least, it shows even if empty. Do not set min-height, but use min-height to element standing in area which are not msg. If msg is empty and no size set, it will collapse on itself

Comment: That's a good idea!